# Enable redhats devtoolset in fish shell

Tags: linux, shell, redhat, fish, devtoolset

Is there an appropriate way to enable devtoolset or any of the rh tools in the fish shell on startup?
Normally in Zsh *(~/.zshrc)* or Bash *(~/.bashrc)* you would add lines similar to:

```
source /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/enable
```

or

```
source scl_source enable devtoolset-7
```

Unfortunately neither of those work in the ~/.config/fish/config.fish since the syntax isn't supported by fish. The only way I know how to do it is manually add all the lines in the enable file to my fish paths.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The question is about software tools used by programmers, so I think it's on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I just found a way to do this. 
The key is to use a third-party tool which allows fish-shell `source` command read bash scripts. I use [bass](https://github.com/edc/bass).

After installing bass, you can simply use `bass source scl_source enable devtoolset-7`
to change gcc version. You can also add it to `~/.config/fish/config.fish` so that it takes effect everytime you log in.

More discussion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/446925/re-use-profile-for-fish).

Answer (score -2):

You can add commands in /etc/fish/config.fish

```
# Put system-wide fish configuration entries here
# or in .fish files in conf.d/
# Files in conf.d can be overridden by the user
# by files with the same name in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fish/conf.d

# This file is run by all fish instances.
# To include configuration only for login shells, use
# if status --is-login
#    ...
# end
# To include configuration only for interactive shells, use
# if status --is-interactive
#   ...
# end
source scl_source enable rh-git29
source scl_source enable rh-postgresql10
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer and explain what it does? That way people can actually understand and learn form it, rather than just copying some code off the web.

Comment: I mentioned above that I tried doing this already in the "~/.config/fish/config.fish". It doesn't work because fishes syntax doesn't support it